# Printing the list new Redditors for a given month from the BigQuery reddit corpus

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to print the list of redditors, who have not posted NOR commented in the last 12 months,  for each month of 2010. I'm using the reddit comment/post corpus on BigQuery for this purpose.

This is what I am running to get new users in January 2010:

```
SELECT author FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2010] WHERE created_utc <= 1264982399 AND author NOT IN 
(SELECT author FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2009]) AND author NOT IN (SELECT author FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512] WHERE created_utc <1420070400)
```

When I run this on BigQuery, I get a "Resources Exceeded" error. If I remove the select statement for [fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512], the query runs fine.

Therefore, presently, I can only get those users who did not comment in the last 12 months, but they may have posted during that time. I would just like a list of users whose "first" activity on reddit was to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you remove duplicates:

```
SELECT author
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2010]
WHERE created_utc <= 1264982399
AND author NOT IN (
  SELECT author
  FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2009]
  GROUP BY 1
)
AND author NOT IN (
  SELECT author
  FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512]
  WHERE created_utc <1420070400
  GROUP BY 1
)
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

(Piggybacking on Felipe's answer) `SELECT DISTINCT` makes an equivalent query with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) a bit simpler:

```
SELECT DISTINCT author
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2010`
WHERE created_utc <= 1264982399
AND author NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT author
  FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2009`
)
AND author NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT author
  FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512`
  WHERE created_utc < 1420070400
);
```